# Export php datatable to pdf version

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, export-to-pdf

I have a datatable containing some data. When i click on the generate report button, it should convert the datatable into pdf version. How can I convert the datatable into pdf version?

Comment: Here is the jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/o92g9goL/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try using mPDF, which converts HTML into PDF.

http://www.mpdf1.com/

Or by using JavaScript:

https://parall.ax/products/jspdf